# Adding a new dropdown box when a button is pressed

Tags: php, html, ajax

So this is the code in my matching.php file that I use to create the first dropdown box :

```
<form method='post' action='/'>
    <?php 
         if(!empty($aIngList)){
            echo "<span style = 'float:left; font-size: 20px;font-family:'Helvetica Neue' class = 'custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white'><select name = 'IngredientName' class = 'custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white'>";
            echo "<option value='' default >Choose an Ingredient</option>";
            foreach ($aIngList as $iIngID => $sIngName) {
                 echo "<option value='".$sIngName."' >".$sIngName."</option>";
                       }
            echo "</select></span>";
                }else{
                      echo "<p>No results available!</p>";
               }
     ?>

 </form>
```

And this uses some previous php code that takes strings from a database and puts them into an array that is used in the code above.

I also have a tag for a button:

```
  <button type="button" class="addbutton" id="button">Add another</button>
```

I don't know how to make it so that when I press this button, it will then display a new dropdown box. Preferably, I'd like to be able to display up to 5 dropdown boxes, depending on how many times the button is clicked - and I don't want previous boxes to disappear or be overwritten once this happens.

I've heard that you can use AJAX to run the PHP as it's server-side but I really don't understand what they've done for the AJAX code part. So if someone could give me a few pointers and maybe explain what each of the AJAX parts does, that would be most appreciated. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Read http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: After you get an idea on what is ajax, read http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: Once you get a fair idea about ajax, think about any javascript framework. I would suggest jQuery. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp